# How to make the content in a horizontally scrollable div broken into two lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code below produces a horizontally scrollable div. I want to make it such that this text: `I want to break this text up into two lines`, is broken into two lines instead of having it on one long line. I tried reducing the width of the `.navigation-item-content` but it didn't break the text into two lines and just moved the `.navigation-item-content` div's around.

Any suggestions? I just can't get it to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
 .navigation {
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      background-color: white;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    
    .navigation-item {
      padding: 12px 11px 7px 11px;
      width: 100%; 
    }
    
    .navigation-item-content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
    }
    
    .navigation-item-title {
      text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navigation">
    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-content">
            <p class="navigation-item-title">
             <span>I want to break this text up into two lines</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-content">
            <p class="navigation-item-title ">
             <span>I want to break this text up into two lines</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-content">
            <p class="navigation-item-title ">
             <span>I want to break this text up into two lines</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-item">
        <div class="navigation-item-content">
            <p class="navigation-item-title ">
             <span>I want to break this text up into two lines</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `<br />` tag?

Comment: Yes I can use that. But I want to do it at a specific width of the screen. How can I do that line break with media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes to your styles. `.navigation` class makes `width: 100%` and `.navigation-item` class add `width` divide 100 by your items number. like:

```
.navigation {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: lightgray;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 12px 11px 7px 11px;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  white-space: normal;
}

.navigation-item-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}    
.navigation-item-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: But it isn't scrollable then.

Comment: you can try now

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a `<br>` tag where you want to break the line,
or you can remove `white-space:nowrap` from the .navigation so that it doesn't all go in the same line

Comment: Yes I can use `br`. But I want to do it at a specific width of the screen. How can I  do that with media queries? If remove `white-space:nowrap` then it doesn't scroll

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a specific width to create the line break and disable the shrinking:

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.navigation-item {
  padding: 12px 11px 7px 11px;
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* don't forget this*/
}

.navigation-item-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation-item">
    <p class="navigation-item-title">
      I want to break this text up into two lines
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-item">
    <p class="navigation-item-title ">
      <span>I want to break this text up into two lines
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-item">
    <p class="navigation-item-title ">
      I want to break this text up into two lines
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-item">
    <p class="navigation-item-title ">
      I want to break this text up into two lines
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```